# URL routing in not condition

Tags: php, routes, pyrocms

I want to call a specific module when url doesnot contail certain words. Eg.: if url is `www.abc.com/articles/a`, I want to route it normally. If url is `www.abc.com`, it should be calling default module. But if url is `www.abc.com/qw/asw`, it should call blog module (Controller).

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out and checked the url this way:

```
$subdir  = substr(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)), strlen(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])));
$tmp_array = explode('?', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$uri = str_replace($subdir, '', $tmp_array[0]);
$uri = ltrim($uri, '/');
$URIParts = explode("/", $uri);


$URIPartsCount = count($URIParts);

if( $URIPartsCount>0 && in_array($URIParts[0],$pages) )
{
    $uripart = $URIParts[0];
    if( in_array($uripart,$somearray) )
    {
        $page = $uripart;
    }
    ...
    else
    {
        $page = "index";
    }
}
else
{
    $page = "index";
}

if( $URIPartsCount>1  )
{
    $todo =  $URIParts[1];
}
else
{
    $todo = "";
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this backwards. Why not route specific URL patterns to the module you would like them to go to? Much easier.

Comment: I am having multiple modules and i had already made some url routings as per my requirements.